# Minimize time consumes for output result

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select * from abc as t where t.num = 8898 order by t.create_dt
select * from abc as t where t.num like '8898' order by t.create_dt
select * from abc as t where t.num like reverse('%8898')  order by t.create_dt
```

which one is fastest?

Comment: Test them and see which is the fastest on your data and your system.

Answer (score 0):

I would say this would be the faster

```
select * from abc as t where t.num = 8898 order by t.create_dt
```

Why is that?

You're comparing an integer but your other two methods is actually comparing a character.

This method is wrong actually but it's usable :

```
select * from abc as t where t.num like '8898' order by t.create_dt
```

LIKE is usually use for string or varchar in the database .

This method is also wrong but it's also usable:

```
select * from abc as t where t.num like reverse('%8898')  order by t.create_dt
```

For an integer , it's best to use `=,=!,>,<,>=,<=`
As for String, it's advisable to use LIKE to find the exact string that contains the value you're looking for . If you want to use a wildcard to find a specific string , you could use like this `LIKE '%something%'`

Answer (score 0):

The first one should be no slower than the others, assuming that `num` is a number.  It can benefit from an index on `abc(num, create_dt)`.

The second might be fast, except that it would be converting `num` to a string.  Without an index, this is a very minor difference from the first.  However, it probably precludes the use of an index.

The third is pretty much the same reasoning.